# Using the Javascript Facebook SDK without HTML

Tags: javascript, facebook, azure, facebook-sdk-4.0, azure-functions

I'm creating a JavaScript Azure Function App. I want to use the Facebook SDK to read information from a page, but the sdk initialization examples I've been able to find say that the SDK initialization should be placed in the HTML head tag, and refers to parts of the html page. Only problem is the app has no HTML frontend (or any HTML whatsoever).

So I'm trying to figure out how to correctly update the following code for a pure js project without losing something important:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'your-app-id',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.9'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean with `..the app has no HTML frontend..`. ? Is it a web app?

Comment: It's an azure javascript function:https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/. JavaScript is one of the choices for the language, along with C# or other languages for a function that fires when a trigger is hit, with no need for a gui.

Comment: do you mean node.js? you can try using a node facebook sdk, i believe there are some.

Comment: That's it. Thank you! https://www.npmjs.com/package/fb turns out to be exactly what I need.